# Should Presenter handle all events of View in MVP design architecture in Android?

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-mvp

Suppose I have a `Button` in my `Activity` which shows me a `Toast` message when it is clicked. Now my question is, should I notify the `Presenter` when my button is clicked and the `Presenter` should decide what the `View` should do or it is not required to notify the `Presenter` and my `View` can itself show a message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though the presenter isn't (currently) supposed to provide any data from the model to be shown in `Toast` upon a button click, it is still a good approach to notify the presenter by the following reasons:

- the view and presenter behaviour might be tested (*instrumentation* and *unit*);
- you might want to provide data from the model to be shown in `Toast` in the future. Such a modification would require less effort.